# Two select all check boxes in a page is not working correctly

Tags: jquery

I have two check boxes in a page.If one check all check box is clicked, the other's check boxes are also enabled with the selected box.

**jQuery**

```
$("#box_all").click(function () {
  $('td input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);
});

$("#book_all").click(function () {
  $('td input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

HTML

```
<th><%= check_box_tag "box_all" %></th>
<td>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'box_id', sd.box.id %>
  <%= check_box_tag "box_dance_ids[]", bd.id %>
</td>

<th><%= check_box_tag "book_all" %></th>
<td ><%= check_box_tag "book_dance[book_ids][]", @book.id %></td>
```

can any body help me

Comment: use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, by doing

```
$('td input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);
```

You are checking all checkboxes that are in a `td` cell. You need to improve your selector.

You did not show us your html so I can only guide you but you can

1. Give a class to those checkboxes or to their tds.

`$('td.my_specific_tds input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);`

1. Pass a container that contains the checkboxes you want to update.

`$('td input[type=checkbox]', $('#my_container_id')).attr('checked', this.checked);`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 $('td input:checkbox:checked[name=<name_of_the_checkbox>]')
```